# PHP fatal Error require_once

Tags: php

Hello Guys can anyone explain why is this happening to my program

when i use this Folder structure

[image]

and the code inside database.php is

```
<?php require_once("../db_config.php");?>
```

I get an error 
`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../db_config.php' (include_path='.;F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\project\database\db_mysql\database.php on line 3'`

but when i move the db_config.php

[image]

Everything works fine. I don't get it. Can anyone explain.I prefer to use the first Folder structure because i will add a new folder db_mssql for mssql database.

Comment: I believe you are on windows and windows prefers backslash to forwardslash

Comment: @Satya thanks but i use all forwardslash in my links and it still working.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php require_once("../db_config.php");?>
```

Try

```
<?php require_once("../../db_config.php");?>
```

Better yet use

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'directory/directory/file');
```

Comment: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory/directory/file');
Thanks this one works. But this code <?php require_once(" ../db_config.php");?>  doesn't work? can you explain why?

Comment: The `../` is the equivilent of a directory in the directory structure.  Each one tells the code to look up to its parent directory. db_config.php is located 2 directories(including the one that it is located in) higher than database.php. It's like folderception!